# "THREE.OBJLoader is not a constructor" and "Unexpected token {" in OBJLoader and OrbitControls

Tags: javascript, three.js, objloader

I'm trying to display an OBJ 3D model as a wireframe that can be moved with OrbitControls using Three.js. I'm new with three.js, so I apologize if I'm missing something "obvious".

I've been able to get a cube to show as a wireframe with OrbitControls.
In a different setup, I was able to display the OBJ 3D model as a wireframe. Therefore, the issue isn't related to the 3D model.

The issue happens when I try to mix both approaches together.

I've tried to go about this in two ways:

1. I tried to insert the OBJLoader into the cube environment. (most promising)
2. I tried to add OrbitControls into the working, but unmovable, wireframe OBJ environment. (didn't really work at all)

Most of the other answers focus on the order of scripts: yes, I have tried to move the `three.min.js`, `OrbitControls.js`, `OBJLoader.js`, and my main working `model.js` into order and disorder, in every possible way.

Here's my code:

```html
<head>
    <style media="screen"> html, body { margin: 0; } #model_container { background-color: #333333; margin: 50px; } </style>
    <title>OBJ Wireframe</title>
    <script defer src="script/three/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="script/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script defer src="script/three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script defer src="script/model.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="model_container"></div>
</body>
```

```js
const globalWidth = window.innerWidth - 100;
const globalHeight = window.innerHeight - 100;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, globalWidth / globalHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.x = 300;
camera.position.y = -6;
camera.position.z = 1;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
   antialias: true,
   alpha: true
});
renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0);
renderer.setSize(globalWidth, globalHeight);

const canvas = document.getElementById("model_container");
canvas.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(ambient);

const loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load("assets/castle.obj", function(object) {
   const geometry = object.children[0].geometry;
   THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
   const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({});
   const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
   mesh.material.wireframe = true;
   scene.add(mesh);
})

const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;
controls.rotateSpeed   = 0.1;
controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);

var animate = function () {
   requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   controls.update();
   renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
animate();
```

Here are the errors I can't fix after 3 days of searching and trying everything I could:

- `OrbitControls.js:9`: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`
- `OBJLoader.js:5`: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`
- `Uncaught TypeError: THREE.OBJLoader is not a constructor at model.js:23`

The errors seem to be rooted in the THREE.js files themselves, which I find very strange. I'm all out of ideas and documentation to go through.

*I'm running this with MAMP, but have also tried uploading to a server to see if the issue is related to being local files or anything similar.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script defer src="script/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script defer src="script/three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
```

It seems you are loading the files from the wrong path. Files from the `jsm` directory are ES6 modules which are imported via ES6 import syntax. Try to include the files from the `js` directory:

```
<script defer src="script/three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script defer src="script/three/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
```

`three.js R106`

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks a lot!